# Замкнутые выражения

Tags: javascript

Чем отличается

```
Obj = function (){
  // properties, methods
}
```

от

```
Obj = (function(){
   // properties, methods
})();
```

По-моему и там и там свойства и методы инкапсулируются.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Объявление анонимной функции

   ```
   var f = function() {
       // code...
   };
   ```
2. Объявление анонимной самовызывающейся функции, т.е. которая сразу же выполнит себя, результат никуда не будет записан.

   ```
   (function() {
      // code...
   })();
   ```
3. Объявление анонимной самовызывающейся функции, т.е. которая сразу же выполнит себя и результат запишет в `f1/f2/f3` соответственно.

   ```
   var f1 = function() {
       // code...
   }();

   var f2 = (function() {
       // code...
   })();

   var f3 = (function() {
       // code...
   }());
   ```

В чем разница между `f1`, `f2`, `f3`? Все просто! `f2` и `f3` делают одно и тоже, но на `f2` будет ругаться `jslint` (если я не путаю). 
Почему функция `f1` не обернута в `()`, потому что эти скобки нужны когда нет присвоения переменной, как в варианте 2. Но обычно пишут как в `f2` и `f3` просто потому, что так нагляднее, скобки в конце `f1` можно и не заметить .)

Answer (score 5):

Если очень просто:

1. Это объявление анонимной функции и сохранение ссылки на неё в переменной obj
2. Создание и выполнение анонимной функции

Пример:

```
var b = 1;
var foo = function (a){
    return a * b;
};

var bar = (function (){
    var b = 2;
    return function (a){
        return a * b;
    };
})();

foo(2); // 2
bar(2); // 4;

b = 3;
foo(2); // 6
bar(2); // 4

// или такой пример
(function inc(num){
    num++;
    if( num < 10 ){
        // какая-то логика
        inc(); // рекурсия 
    }
})(0);
```

Для более глубокого погружения, советую прочитать Дмитрия Сошникова — [Тонкости ECMA-262-3. Часть 5. Функции.](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/ru-chapter-5-functions/)

Comment: Когда после списка идет код, нужно делать двойной отступ для подсветки кода (толи это баг, толи фича, но она уже давно)

Comment: @lampa, это баг

Comment: Перенос не помогал, пришлось "Пример" вписать.

Comment: чет вы перемудрили, нормальные примеры вот:

    var foo = function (a){
        return a ;
    };

    var bar = (function (a){   
      return  a;
    })(5);

    console.log(foo);
    console.log(bar);

Comment: Нет, в вашем случае:

   console.log(foo); // function
   console.log(bar); // 5

Comment: Поймите, второй вариант нужен только для создания обособленной области видимости для скрытая от внешнего контекста вспомогательных переменных.

Answer (score 0):

Например, в этой статье почитайте: [An Important Pair of Parens](http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/an-important-pair-of-parens).

Comment: Статья прямо в точку, но я и русский-то толком не понимаю, чтобы читать на английском